# Verifying form the proof of product theorem of limit

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification

I came up with this proof about Product theorem of limits after I watched "MIT
Calculus Revisited" and I hope it's OK:

**primal work on proof**

*Given* $\hspace{0.5in}$ $$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to a} f\left( x \right) = K \hspace{0.1in} and \hspace{0.1in} \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to a} g\left( x \right) = L$$

*we hope to prove the existence of*  $$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to a} [f\left( x \right) \cdot g\left( x \right)]= L \cdot K$$ *means by Epsilon Delta definition* :

$\hspace{1.4in}$every number $\varepsilon  > 0$ there is some number $\delta  > 0$ such that $$\left| {(f\left( x \right)  \cdot g\left( x \right))-(L \cdot K) } \right| < \varepsilon \hspace{0.5in}{\mbox{whenever}}\hspace{0.5in}0 < \left| {x - a} \right| <  \delta$$

$\hspace{.91in} \vert{(f\left( x \right) \cdot g\left( x \right))\vert-\vert(L \cdot K)\vert }  < \varepsilon\hspace{.2in}  \text{By Triangular inequality (1)}  $

$\hspace{.91in} \vert{f\left( x \right)\vert \cdot \vert g\left( x \right)\vert-
{\vert L \vert \cdot \vert K \vert}}  < \varepsilon \hspace{0.2in} \text{by absoluate value product (2) }$

$\hspace{.91in} \vert{K + (f\left( x \right)-K) \vert \cdot \vert L + (g\left( x \right)-L)\vert-
{\vert L \vert \cdot \vert K \vert}}  < \varepsilon \hspace{0.2in}\text{Adding zeros)(3) }$

$\hspace{.91in} { \vert L \vert \cdot \vert(f\left( x \right)-K) \vert +\vert K \vert \cdot \vert(g\left( x \right)-L)\vert{}+\vert f\left( x \right)-K \cdot g\left( x \right)-L\vert }  < \varepsilon \hspace{.08in}\text{simplify(4)}$

$\hspace{.9in}$put $\vert L \vert \cdot \vert f\left( x \right)-K\vert <  \varepsilon/3$

$\hspace{.9in}$put $\vert K \vert \cdot \vert g\left( x \right)-L\vert <  \varepsilon/3$

$\hspace{.9in}$put $\vert f\left( x \right)-K\vert < \sqrt{\varepsilon/3}$

$\hspace{.9in}$put $\vert g\left( x \right)-L\vert <  \sqrt{\varepsilon/3}$

**Actual proof**

let $\varepsilon > 0 \hspace{0.1in}$ chooes $\varepsilon_1 = \varepsilon/3$
 $\hspace{0.1in}$ and  $\hspace{0.1in}$ $\varepsilon_2 = \varepsilon/3 \hspace{0.1in}$   then there exist

$\delta_1 > 0 \hspace{0.1in} $ such that $ \hspace{0.1in} \left \vert L \vert \cdot \vert {f\left( x \right) -K } \right| < \varepsilon_1 = \varepsilon/3 \hspace{0.2in}{\mbox{whenever}}\hspace{0.2in}0 < \left| {x - a} \right| <  \delta_1 $

$\delta_2 > 0 \hspace{0.1in} $ such that $ \hspace{0.1in} \left \vert K \vert \cdot \vert {g\left( x \right) -L } \right| < \varepsilon_2 = \varepsilon/3 \hspace{0.2in}{\mbox{whenever}}\hspace{0.2in}0 < \left| {x - a} \right| <  \delta_2 $

also choose $\varepsilon_3 = \sqrt{\varepsilon/3}$
 $\hspace{0.1in}$ and  $\hspace{0.1in}$ $\varepsilon_4 =\sqrt{\varepsilon/3} \hspace{0.1in}$   then there exist

$\delta_3 > 0 \hspace{0.1in} $ such that $ \hspace{0.1in} \left \vert {f\left( x \right) -K } \right| < \varepsilon_3 = \sqrt{\varepsilon/3} \hspace{0.2in}{\mbox{whenever}}\hspace{0.2in}0 < \left| {x - a} \right| <  \delta_3 $

$\delta_4 > 0 \hspace{0.1in} $ such that $ \hspace{0.1in} \left \vert {g\left( x \right) -L } \right| < \varepsilon_4 = \sqrt{\varepsilon/3} \hspace{0.2in}{\mbox{whenever}}\hspace{0.2in}0 < \left| {x - a} \right| <  \delta_4 $

choose the $\delta=\min(\delta_1,\delta_2,\delta_3,\delta_4)$ then :

$$
  \begin{pmatrix}
  \hspace{0.1in} \left \vert L \vert \cdot \vert {f\left( x \right) -K } \right| < \varepsilon_1 = \varepsilon/3\\
  \hspace{0.1in} \left \vert K \vert \cdot \vert {g\left( x \right) -L } \right| < \varepsilon_2 = \varepsilon/3\\
   \hspace{0.1in} \left   \vert {f\left( x \right) -K } \right| < \varepsilon_3 = \sqrt{\varepsilon/3}\\
   \hspace{0.1in} \left   \vert {g\left( x \right) -L } \right| < \varepsilon_4 = \sqrt{\varepsilon/3}\\
   \end{pmatrix}
$$
Will all hold for $\delta$

Adding the first two inequalities and Multiplying the last two inequalities we will get

$\hspace{.91in} { \vert L \vert \cdot \vert(f\left( x \right)-K) \vert +\vert K \vert \cdot \vert(g\left( x \right)-L)\vert{}+\vert f\left( x \right)-K \cdot g\left( x \right)-L\vert }  < \varepsilon$ ${\mbox{whenever}}\hspace{2in}0 < \left| {x - a} \right| <  \delta$

and that is what we looking for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why did Michael Spivak pick $\frac{\epsilon}{2(|m|+1)}$? Why didn't he start with arbitrary $\epsilon$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/864538/why-did-michael-spivak-pick-frac-epsilon2m1-why-didnt-he-start-wit)

Answer (score 1):

I think your proof is correct, but perhaps the choice of $\sqrt{\varepsilon/3}$ is not the most desirable, since you may need to show that if $\varepsilon$ is small, then $\sqrt\varepsilon$ is still small. In other words, that $\sqrt{x}\to 0$ when $x\to 0$.

To avoid such mess, the standard trick is to do as follows:
$$|f(x)\cdot g(x) - LK| = |f(x)\cdot g(x) - f(x)\cdot L + f(x)\cdot L - KL| \leq $$
$$\leq |f(x)\cdot g(x) - f(x)\cdot L| + |f(x)\cdot L - KL|$$

Can you continue from here?

Comment: At first I think it is intuitively to consider  $\sqrt\varepsilon$ will approach 0 as $\varepsilon$ approach 0 and by the restriction $\varepsilon$ > 0 we will guarantee also that any value under square root will be positive , for example look at the table : 


$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
\varepsilon& \ \sqrt{\varepsilon/3} \\
\hline
1 & 0.577 \\
0.1 & 0.182 \\
0.01 & 0.057 \\
0.001 & 0.0182\\
0.0001 & 0.00577\\
... &  ...
\end{array}
$$

Comment: and second, for the expression $ |f(x)\cdot g(x) - f(x)\cdot K| + |f(x)\cdot K - LK| = |f(x)|[(g(x)-K)]+|K|[f(x)-L]$

Note that i have no control over$|g(x)-K|$ and $|f(x)-L|$

thank You

Comment: Yes, to the first comment, it is of course true, but perhaps it is not very common in this particular proof. To the second comment, I mistook K for L. I have corrected it now.

Comment: $|f(x)\cdot g(x) - f(x)\cdot L| + |f(x)\cdot L - KL| = |f(x)| |(g(x)-L)| + |L| |f(x)-K|$

OK but I do not know how to control $|f(x)|$ ?!

Comment: $|f(x)| \leq |f(x) - K| + |K|$

Comment: Can you please verify form this : 
 
$|f(x)\cdot g(x) - LK| = |f(x)\cdot g(x) - f(x)\cdot L + f(x)\cdot L - KL|$ $ \hspace{1.4in}$$\leq |f(x)\cdot g(x) - f(x)\cdot L| + |f(x)\cdot L - KL|$

$\hspace{1.4in}$$=|f(x)[g(x)-L]|+|L[f(x)-k]|$
$\hspace{1.4in}$$=|f(x)|.|g(x)-L|+|L|.|f(x)-k|$
$\hspace{1.4in}\leq|f(x)-k|+|k|.|g(x)-L|+|L|.|f(x)-k|$ 
$\hspace{1.4in}=|f(x)-K|[|K|.|g(x)-L|+|L|]$

put $|f(x)-K| <  \varepsilon/2$

put $|K|.|g(x)-L|+|L| < 2$

and by multiplying  $\varepsilon/2\hspace{0.01in}.2 = \varepsilon$

Comment: OK, you will not perhaps be able to guarantee that $|L| < 2$ (since $|L|$ is already given to you) but:
 - let $M>0$ be so that $|L|, |K| < M$
 - now let $|f(x)-K| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2M}$

Comment: I think i done a mistake above, I Wrote the proof again:

$|f(x)\cdot g(x) - LK| = |f(x)\cdot g(x) - f(x)\cdot L + f(x)\cdot L - KL|$ $ \hspace{1.4in}$$\leq |f(x)\cdot g(x) - f(x)\cdot L| + |f(x)\cdot L - KL|$

$\hspace{1.4in}$$=|f(x)[g(x)-L]|+|L[f(x)-K]|$
$\hspace{1.4in}$$=|f(x)|.|g(x)-L|+|L|.|f(x)-K|$
$\hspace{1.4in}$$\leq|f(x)-K|+|K|.|g(x)-L|+|L|.|f(x)-K|$
$\hspace{1.4in}$$=|f(x)-K|(1+|K|.|g(x)-L|+|L|)$
$\hspace{1.4in}$$=|f(x)-K|(1+|K|.|g(x)|)$

Put|M|>0 then $1+|K|.|g(x)|\leq |M|$

Put $|f(x)-K|< |\varepsilon/M|$

$\hspace{1.4in}$$=|f(x)-k|(1+|K|.|g(x)|)<|\varepsilon/M|.|M|$

Comment: You made a mistake above. From $|f(x)|\cdot |g(x)-L| + |L| + |f(x)-K|$, let
   
$|L|, |K| < M$ ;
   
$|f(x)-L| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2M}$ ; and
  
$|g(x)-M| < \frac{\varepsilon}{4M}$.  
Assume also that $\varepsilon < 1 < M$. Then
$$|f(x)| \leq |f(x)-L| + |L| < \varepsilon + M < 2M$$
so 
$|f(x)|\cdot |g(x)-L| + |L| + |f(x)-K| \leq ...$

Comment: OK I will Try to prove it with your new hints 
but can you tell me what exactly type of mistake that I've done with my proof to avoid it next time ?

Comment: In your last step, you wrote
$|g(x)-L| +|L| = |g(x)|$